# Windows 7 + Dialup Network Connection ("Wizard cannot create the connection")

Tags: active-directory, windows-7, dialup

We have a banking application[1] that requires a Dialup Connection object to establish it's connection.

We've recently upgraded to Windows 7 and are unable to create the connection; the error message is "The wizard cannot create the connection" with no error codes or anything useful.

We have tried:

- Create the DUN as Domain Administrator = works, but not available to the user.
- Create the DUN as Local Administrator = works, but not available to the user.
- Push the DUN using Group Policy = `gpresult` and `rsop` says the policy has applied successfully, but the DUN is not in Networking and Connections panel.
- Adding the domain user to the Local Administrator group = Same error.
- Disabling UAC = Same error.
- Creating a test user on a test computer, both in their own OU and blocking all Group Policies = Same error.

There appears to be no logs in the event log, and funnily enough there is not much information on the internet about Windows 7 + Active Directory + Dialup.

[1] *Yes this is a legacy application, there is an upgrade path to an online web application, but we're not quite in the position to upgrade it yet*